# File based h2 persisted but not loaded in Spring Boot

Tags: java, maven, hsqldb, h2, spring-boot

I made a small application based on Spring Boot:

- spring-boot-starter-web
- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

The application has simply one domain class `Post.java`.
Accordingly there is a RestController and a DAO.
The data is supposed to be persisted in a file based hsql db.

When the application is running everything seems fine. Data is stored.
The h2 file is created and contains insert statements.

However, when I kill the application and start it a second time. No data is loaded. (As if a brand new db file was created, which overwrote the old one).

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:file:~/testdb
spring.datasource.username = sa
spring.datasource.password = sa
spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.h2.Driver
```

**pom.xml**

```
<!-- Spring Boot Web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring Boot Data JPA -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- H2 DB -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.179</version>
</dependency>
```

**PostDAO.java**

```
public interface PostDAO extends JpaRepository<Post, Integer>{
    public Post findByMessage(String message);
}
```

**Post.java**

```
@Entity
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String message;

    public Post(){
    }

    public Post(String message) {
        super();
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide updated pom.xml, application.properties, and any other changes you made to get this to work. Thanks.

Comment: In this case you just need to add `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate` to your application.properties file. @SrkiRakic

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The default for `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` is `create-drop` if you use an embedded database. You probably want it to be empty, or just `validate` (`none` might work as well but I think that's deprecated by hibernate).

Comment: That was it. Thanks! Even though I assumed Spring would detect the correct behaviour automatically: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html